# Unwrap array of dictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionary from firebase like bellow :

```
"gcm.notification.data" = "{\"request\":\"update_location\",\"latitude\":\"45.48945419494574\",\"customMessage\":{\"loc-args\":[\"iPhone di Tester\"],\"loc-key\":\"LOCATION_CHECKIN\"},\"type\":\"checkin\",\"message\":\"Ggg\",\"longitude\":\"9.195329826333742\",\"child\":{\"name\":\"iPhone di Tester\",\"pid\":\"C312EDDC-E8A8-4EFC-9E65-957BE5DAC5FC\"}}";
```

I tried to unwrap the request, like bellow but it crash, can anyone help.

```
 NSDictionary *gcmnotificationdat = [userInfo objectForKey:@"gcm.notification.data"];
    NSString *request = [gcmnotificationdat objectForKey:@"request"];
```

Comment: `gcmnotificationdat` is a `NSString` (JSON Stringified it seems so), not a `NSDictionary`. The error message that you don't give should tell you so. You need to do `NSString *gcmnotificationdatString = [userInfo objectForKey:@"gcm.notification.data"]; NSString *gcmnotificationdatData = [gcmnotificationdatString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSDictionary *gcmnotificationdat = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:gcmnotificationdatData options:0 error:nil];`

Comment: HI @Larme, the gcmnotificationdatData it doesn't work with dataUsingEncoding.

Comment: it works thanks :) I was confusing, you right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a crash. As a developer it's important to read it. You can either understand it or not, but you can certainly look for it, and this one is quite known. It's a basic crash message that any iOS developer should know.
If you don't, share it with us. You'll get better chances to get answers.

The most important part being:

```
-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100002090
```

It means that you are trying to call a method `objectForKey:` on a `NSString` object. `NSString` doesn't know it, and that's why it crashes.

The value of key `gcm.notification.data` is a JSON Stringified.

So `[userInfo objectForKey:@"gcm.notification.data"];` is in fact a `NSString` not a `NSDictionary`.

Let's fix it now:

```
//Creation of the sample for the sake of the test
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"gcm.notification.data": @"{\"request\":\"update_location\",\"latitude\":\"45.48945419494574\",\"customMessage\":{\"loc-args\":[\"iPhone di Tester\"],\"loc-key\":\"LOCATION_CHECKIN\"},\"type\":\"checkin\",\"message\":\"Ggg\",\"longitude\":\"9.195329826333742\",\"child\":{\"name\":\"iPhone di Tester\",\"pid\":\"C312EDDC-E8A8-4EFC-9E65-957BE5DAC5FC\"}}"};

//Parsing
NSString *gcmNotificationJSONString = [userInfo objectForKey:@"gcm.notification.data"];
NSData *gcmNotificationJSONData = [gcmNotificationJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *gcmNotification = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:gcmNotificationJSONData options:0 error:nil];
NSString *request = [gcmNotification objectForKey:@"request"];
NSLog(@"Request: %@", request);
```

Note: I removed the "dat" part of the var names, that you used because the key ends with "data" to not confuse `NSString`, `NSData` and `NSDictionary` as I explicitly named them from the class. I mistype a class in the comment, be careful and fix it from the code here.