# How do I properly return as JSON-ified version of Parse object?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm hitting a custom function on my server, getting a `PFObject` in my `Convos` objects and returning that object from JS, which results in this string in my Objective-C code:

`"<convos: 0x6080002ae220, objectId: e1VYAIFCyQ, localId: (null)> {
\n    buyerDeleted = NO;\n    buyerId = NNfjWZrk8r;\n    buyerPicture = \"<PFFile: 0x60800065de80>\";\n    buyerSentMessage = YES;\n    buyerSentTwoMessages = YES;\n    buyerUnseen = 0;\n    buyerUser = \"<PFUser: 0x6080002f1900, objectId: NNfjWZrk8r, localId: (null)>\";\n    buyerUsername = corby;\n    convoId = bQLQWNEtwmNNfjWZrk8r;\n    lastSent = \"<messages: 0x60c0000b8600, objectId: iYVIjJ6A3q, localId: (null)>\";\n    lastSentDate = \"2018-06-05 19:09:52 +0000\";\n    profileConvo = YES;\n    sellerDeleted = NO;\n    sellerId = bQLQWNEtwm;\n    sellerSentMessage = YES;\n    sellerUnseen = 0;\n    sellerUser = \"<PFUser: 0x6080002f1a80, objectId: bQLQWNEtwm, localId: (null)>\";\n    sellerUsername = tough;\n    source = profile;\n    totalMessages = 3;\n
}"`

I'm trying to take the `convo` object in my JS and run `convo.toJSON()` on it (which seems like the solution) and then return it but that seems to take an extremely long time.

Any tips on how to return that Parse object so that I can ultimately turn it into an `NSDictionary` and then a `PFObject` in the client?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684306/unwrap-array-of-dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

I think we got you covered in slack, but for anyone else who finds this:

Don't use `toJSON()` from your server, just return the `Parse.Object`

In your Obj-C code, add this line to the success block of your call back:
`PFObject *resultParseObject = (PFObject*)object`, where `object` is the `_Nullable id object` parameter to the callback of your cloud function.